# Put text boxes in separate lines

Tags: java, swing, textbox, jtextarea, layout-manager

```
MainClass(){
    JFrame main = new JFrame("Login Form ");
    main.setBounds(350,150,500,500);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    name = new JTextField(10);
    pass = new JTextField(10);
    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    main.add(pane);
    main.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
    pane.add(name);
    //main.add(pane);
    pane.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
    pane.add(pass);
    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    pane.add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(new Handler());
}
```

I want to separate the text boxes in separate lines after the label `username` and `name` text box.  I need to control the cursor to a new line.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (e.g. like what I posted in reply).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i want to separate the text boxes in separate lines

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MainClass {

    JTextField name;
    // This should be a JPasswordField!
    JTextField pass;
    JButton submit;

    MainClass(){
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Login Form ");
        // Don't use this nonsense!
        //main.setBounds(350,150,500,500);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        name = new JTextField(10);
        pass = new JTextField(10);
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        main.add(pane);
        pane.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
        pane.add(name);
        pane.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        pane.add(pass);
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        pane.add(submit);
        //submit.addActionListener(new Handler());
        main.pack();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
    }
}
```

---

If I was building a login screen, it might be laid out more along these lines (with the labels right justified and the button in it's own panel - left as an exercise for the reader).

[image: Log-In frame]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class MainClass {

    JTextField name;
    JPasswordField pass;
    JButton submit;

    MainClass(){
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Login Form ");
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        name = new JTextField(10);
        pass = new JPasswordField(10);

        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        main.setContentPane(gui);

        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        gui.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
        gui.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        labels.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
        controls.add(name);
        labels.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        controls.add(pass);
        submit = new JButton("Submit");

        gui.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        main.pack();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW - save yourself some trouble and change the `JFrame` for a (modal) `JDialog`.

Comment: can u help me to move this login form to the CENTRE of screen

Comment: *"move this login form to the CENTRE of screen"* Call `main.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` *"can u help"* Can you please type all the letters of 'you'?  This is a comment on a technical Q&A site, not a text message.

Answer (score 1):

Use BoxLayout; create a JPanel, use SetLayout to set it to BoxLayout, and set the BoxLayout to PAGE_AXIS.  Then things you add go one after another vertically down the 'page'.  There are options for alignment, see the API for BoxLayout or the Oracle/Sun/Java tutorial on layout managers.